# Christmas collaborations and gamification continue all over the year?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Every year in closest days to Christmas we see that Gamification Scores and masks on avatar starting and motivate us to active in Stack Exchange.

My question about continuous strategy in all over the world in SharePoint. Why does this project stop at the beginning of the next year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fun of adding additional badges represented by hats every year wouldn't be as fun if it was available all year around. My guess is, when a lot of users have vacation due to the holiday, SE want to keep up the hit rates of the sites (which drives commercial revenue).

So having this event to celebrate all learning users and keep the site running at full speed wouldn't have the same effect if it was available all year. And I wouldn't be as excited if there where hats all the time. With or without Unicorns :-)

Comment: unicorn? what unicorns? they forgot about the unicorns once again. No unicorn hat ;_;